# Tensorflow Multi-GPU Training (A100), volatile utilization. How to resolve?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, multi-gpu

Currently I am training a CNN for medical applications on a Nvidia DGX Workstation with 4xA100 Graphics cards with mirrored strategy.
The CPU is an AMD EPYC 7742 and the workstation has 512 GB of RAM.

The niftii images were sliced and then stored as **TFRecords**. With those I create my **tf.data.datasets** in parallel with **num_parallel_reads=tf.data.AUTOTUNE**.
The mapping to the features is done in parallel with **num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE**).
The dataset gets shuffled, batched, and prefetched. (somehow, caching did slow down the training by a factor of 1.5-2)

The odd behavior that I am observing now with **nividia-smi -l**:

The first output is something like:

> GPU1 : 0% utilization 
> GPU2 : 100% utilization 
> GPU3 : 100% utilization
> GPU4 : 100% utilization

The second output is:

> GPU1 : 100% utilization 
> GPU2 : 0% utilization 
> GPU3 : 0% utilization
> GPU4 : 0% utilization

The third output is something like:

> GPU1 : 40% utilization 
> GPU2 : 94% utilization 
> GPU3 : 78% utilization
> GPU4 : 100% utilization

and then it repeats with *slightly* different numbers.

Is there any solution to it, that I can utilize my graphics cards almost at 100% all the time and don't waste some computational resources?

The batch size is already as high as possible.

The data loader is basically:

```
   def get_dataset(filename):
      dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename, num_parallel_reads=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
      dataset = dataset.map(
                    parse_tfr_element, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
   return dataset
```

with the parse_tfr_element function from the Tensorflow reference tailored to my needs.

```
dataset_train = get_TFRecord.get_dataset(train_file_list)
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(buffer_size = steps_train)
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset_train = dataset_train.repeat()
dataset_train = dataset_train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

So it is very basic.

Comment: Maybe there is a bottleneck in your dataloader, have you tried increasing the number of workers in your data loading pipeline?

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi, I edited my original post to show my data loader. My intention was that the tf.data.AUTOTUNE  does automatically find the best num of workers for parallel workloads. However, my first test was with 4, second with 8 and so on, until I had 32 parallel workers, which did not improve this behavior.